# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status (Pebble - C)

Tags: c, pebble-watch, cloudpebble

I am a programmer with a strong Java for Android background. I am very new to C and am only learning it to write companion apps for Pebble. **EDIT:** I am using cloudpebble, so I have no control over libraries.

This is a summary of the part of my code where I think the problem is:

```
#include <pebble.h>

static int s_time_a_min;
static int s_time_a_h;
static int s_time_b_min = 0;
static int s_time_b_h = 0;
static int s_time_b_total;
char* c_time_string_min;
char* c_time_string_h;

int str_cut(char *str, int begin, int len){ //I got this method from the internet
    int l = strlen(str);

    if (len < 0) len = l - begin;
    if (begin + len > l) len = l - begin;
    memmove(str + begin, str + begin + len, l - len + 1);

    return len;
}

static void update_text(){
    time_t current_time;

    c_time_string_min = ctime(&current_time); //set these two strings the same: current time
    c_time_string_h = ctime(&current_time); //they are only strings so that they can be substringed

    c_time_string_min = str_cut(c_time_string_min, 14, 16); //substring so that the each string has either min or h
    c_time_string_h = str_cut(c_time_string_h, 11, 13); 

    s_si_h = atoi(c_time_string_h); //make the strings integers so that I can do math with them
    s_si_min = atoi(c_time_string_min);

    s_time_b_total = (((s_si_h) * 3600) + ((s_si_min) * 60)) * (123/99); //do some math. Don't ask what it's for.

    do{
        s_time_b_total = s_time_b_total - 10000; //do some more math. Also don't ask what it's for.
        s_time_b_h = s_time_b_h + 1;
    }while(s_ra_all > 10000);

    do{
        s_time_b_total = s_time_b_total - 100;
        s_time_b_min = s_time_b_min + 1;
    }while(s_ra_all > 100);

    //Here is where I think the problem lies.
    const char* buf = (char)(((int)0)+s_time_b_h) + ":" + (char)(((int)0)+s_time_b_min); //create a string that merges the two integers together and puts a colon in the middle                        

    text_layer_set_text(s_time_layer, buf); //Set text
}
```

And then there's the usual Window_load, main, init, etc.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: your problem is not with the code, but when linking you are failing to include some library(ies)?

Comment: That's a linker error, not a compiler error. Showing us your code won't help. How are you trying to link? What's the complete error?

Comment: Note: Do not think 2 calls to `c_time_string_min = ctime(&current_time); c_time_string_h = ctime(&current_time);` would always return the same time.

Comment: Note: In C, `* (123/99)` is the same as `* (1)`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, simple addition of numbers will not form a string.

Instead, create a buffer and print to it.

```
// const char* buf = (char)(((int)0)+s_time_b_h) + ":" + 
//    (char)(((int)0)+s_time_b_min);

//create a string that merges 2 integers together and puts a colon in the middle
char   buf[100];
sprintf(buf, "%d:%d", s_time_b_h, s_time_b_min);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the linker error, it's impossible to know what the problem is. A common reason for a linker error to occur is when a symbol can't be resolved. This happens when you have a function prototype or variable declaration, but no definition. Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern char *foo;
int main(void) { printf("%s\n", foo); return 0; }
```

When compiling, you'll see this sort of output:

```
[dho@zendev ~]$ cc test.c -o test
/tmp/cc2ec2wu.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This error comes up at the link phase because the compiler knows enough about the size of the type to generate all the relevant code. When linking the final binary, the location of the variable's storage is unknown. Similarly, consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int foo(void);
int main(void) { foo(); return 0; }
```

And

```
[dho@zendev ~]$ cc test.c -o test
/tmp/cc8tgEsT.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here again, we see that there's enough information for the compiler to work, but when linking, we can't find a definition of the foo symbol.

In your code, there are two symbols that are neither declared nor defined: `text_layer_set_text` and `s_time_layer`. It is possible that `pebble.h` declares these symbols, but you are not linking properly to resolve them. I would expect to see this in the case that you have done something like

```
cc test.c -o test
```

Instead of

```
cc test.c -o test -lpebble
```

The line you have highlighted couldn't possibly cause the linker error, but it is problematic. In C, the `+` operator does not concatenate strings. Thus this line does not do what you think it is doing:

```
const char* buf = (char)(((int)0)+s_time_b_h) + ":" + (char)(((int)0)+s_time_b_min);
```

Furthermore, casting an integer to a character does not make that integer representable as a character string with the same logical value. (i.e. `int i = 42; char c = (char)i;` -> `c` is `'*'`, not `"42"`). `s_time_b_h` and `s_time_b_min` are also not integers, they are pointers to character. A string in C is a contiguous byte stream of characters that is terminated by a `NUL` byte (you'll see "NULL byte" thrown around, but that's not really super correct). It's pretty clear from this line that you're not familiar with [dynamic memory allocation or C strings](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx11.html), which differ heavily from Java.

The strings you populate from `ctime(3)` have the form:

```
"Wed Jun 30 21:49:08 1993\n"
```

Thus, they contain newlines. Even if your code worked as intended, the output of `buf` would look like:

```
|Wed Jun 30 21:49:08 1993
:Wed Jun 30 21:49:08 1993
|
```

In this example, I have used the pipe character to show where the start and end of the string would be.

Your calls to `ctime(3)` are flawed. Your value `current_time` is uninitialized, and so the output of `ctime(3)` is undefined. Additionally, `ctime(3)` is not a re-entrant function, so your two calls to it overwrite eachother. Because `ctime(3)` has a second-level granularity, this probably isn't a problem given your example -- both calls will finish in the same second, and they both use the same input seed (`current_time`). To do this correctly, you would need (for example):

```
time_t current_time;
char *s_time_b_h;

current_time = time(NULL);
s_time_b_h = ctime(&current_time);
```

Because `ctime(3)` isn't re-entrant, and you want two values, you'll need to allocate memory for them somewhere. You could do this simply without worrying about dynamic memory allocation:

```
/* 
 * ctime(3) says "The reentrant version ctime_r() does the same, 
 * but stores the string in a user-supplied buffer which should have 
 * room for at least 26 bytes."
 *
 * 26 is length of string plus newline plus NUL byte.
 */
#define CTIME_MAX_LEN 26
char h_buf[CTIME_MAX_LEN], min_buf[CTIME_MAX_LEN];
time_t current_time;
char *s_time_b_h, *s_time_b_min;

current_time = time(NULL);
s_time_b_h = ctime_r(&current_time, h_buf);
if (s_time_b_h == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
s_time_b_min = ctime_r(&current_time, h_buf);
if (s_time_b_min == NULL) {
    return -1;
}

/* Get rid of newlines that you probably don't want */
h_buf[CTIME_MAX_LEN - 2] = '\0';
min_buf[CTIME_MAX_LEN - 2] = '\0';

/* 
 * CTIME_MAX_LEN * 2 is enough space for both times, the
 * additional 2 bytes is enough for the colon and NUL-byte.
 */
char o_buf[CTIME_MAX_LEN * 2 + 2];
snprintf(o_buf, sizeof (o_buf), "%s:%s", h_buf, min_buf);
text_layer_set_text(s_time_layer, o_buf);
```

Of course, until you use different values for the calls to `ctime_r(3)`, both sides will be the same. And until you fix the linker error, you'll still be unable to test this code.